# Get all TF2 item pngs

Tags: json, api

Is there any way to get (for instance) a json with links to icons of all the tf2 items? I am currently developing a something like python backpack viewer, and I thing it'd better if it showed item icons. Is there maybe an official API, or the only way is to take them from TF2 gcf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't see url for item icon in GetSchema json. There are 512x512 and 128x128 versions available in schema.result.items.[item].image_url_large or schema.result.items.[item].image_url